Problem during git commit : Error: mkdir --path-format=absolute
When I tried to commit my files on my local repository, VS Code return to me a non understandable error :
Error: mkdir --path-format=absolute
.git/info: no such file or directory

I tried cleaning and clearing the cache : Nothing working.

After several Google search, I found the solution : mv .git/hooks .git/hooks_backup. Now I ca commit again.

For those facing this issue with Lefthook, a workaround for now is to use version 1.8.2, as stated by one of the maintainers (https://github.com/evilmartians/lefthook/issues/876#issuecomment-2484910614).

I done several test and I removed hook from git. Now I'm able to commit my code on the repository :
$ echo "Test commit" > commit_message.txt
$ git commit -F commit_message.txt

Error: mkdir --path-format=absolute 
.git/info: no such file or directory

$ mv .git/hooks .git/hooks_backup
$ git commit -F commit_message.txt

[dev eb27e22] Test commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

